# Script to return the greatest number and the frequency of the greatest number

Tags: bash, scripts

I have to write a script that takes some numbers as input. I need to get the greatest number and also the frequency of the greatest number. How would I go about this. Would I have to use a for loop?

This is what I have:

```
while read -p "Enter a value:" NUMBER ; do
if [[ $NUMBER -eq 0 ]] : then
   break
else 
    if [[ $NUMBER -gt $max_Value ]] ; then
        max_Value=$NUMBER
    fi
fi
done
```

Comment: Presumably this is an assignment or exercise? If so, the "right" answer likely depends on the learning objectives of your class. Perhaps you are expected to use an [associative array](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)?

Comment: This is an assignment. No array!

Comment: This is not really a question about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation does not use structures. I corrected typo and used your coding style:

```bsh
max_Freq=0 # initialization of frequency (because of increment below can work)
while read -p "Enter a value:" NUMBER ; do
if [[ $NUMBER -eq 0 ]] ; then
   break; # exit while with entering 0
else 
    if [[ $NUMBER -eq $max_Value ]] ; then
        max_Freq=$((max_Freq+1)) # increment frequency of max
    fi
    if [[ $NUMBER -gt $max_Value ]] ; then # we have new max number entered
        max_Value=$NUMBER # remember this number
        max_Freq=1 # initialization of frequency of this number
    fi
fi
done
# on exit while loop print out statistics
echo "Max value $max_Value was entered $max_Freq times";

# Usage example:
# $ bash m.sh 
# Enter a value:4
# Enter a value:4
# Enter a value:5
# Enter a value:0
# Max value 5 was entered 1 times
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation please?